# Exception in Gtk.NodeView.AddNode

Tags: c#, gtk#

I'm getting an exception when I want to add elements into my NodeView:

> Exception in Gtk# callback delegate
>    Note: Applications can use GLib.ExceptionManager.UnhandledException to handle the exception.
>   System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
>    at Gtk.NodeStore.get_value_cb (Int32 node_idx, Int32 col, GLib.Value& val) [0x00000] 
>     at GLib.ExceptionManager.RaiseUnhandledException(System.Exception e, Boolean is_terminal)
>     at Gtk.NodeStore.get_value_cb(Int32 node_idx, Int32 col, Value ByRef val)
>     at Gtk.Application.gtk_main()
>     at Gtk.Application.Run()
>     at IcePipe.Program.Main(System.String[] args) in /home/tomcatfort/Projects/IcePipe/GUI/Program.cs:line 18

I'm making this code in mono 2.4.2.3. And I'm using Gtk#.
You can download my code from this link: http://tomcatfort.net/priv/IcePipe.tar.gz

I don't know what cause the problem, I can't find anything that might be the problem.

Here is the code that throws the exception:

```
public MainWindow () : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
{
    this.Build();
    mContactsNodeStore.AddNode(new Contact("Kutya", new Gdk.Pixbuf("Img/Refresh24x24.png"))); //AddNode(...) throws it. 
}
```

Creating a Contact instance does not cause exception, i tried it.

This is how i made the NodeView:

```
mContactsNodeStore = new NodeStore(typeof(Contact));
mContactsNodeView = new NodeView(mContactsNodeStore);
mContVBox2.PackStart(mContactsNodeView, true, true, 0);
mContactsNodeView.AppendColumn("Icon", new CellRendererPixbuf(), "pixbuf", 0);
mContactsNodeView.AppendColumn("Name", new CellRendererText(), "text", 1);
```

And here is Contact:

```
[Gtk.TreeNode (ListOnly = true)] //What is this for?
public class Contact : Gtk.TreeNode, IDisposable
{
    #region Fields and properties
    [Gtk.TreeNodeValue (Column = 1)]
    private string pName;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the contact.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name {
        get {return pName;}
        protected set {pName = value;}
    }

    [Gtk.TreeNodeValue (Column = 0)]
    private Gdk.Pixbuf pIcon;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the icon of the contact.
    /// </summary>
    public Gdk.Pixbuf Icon {
        get {return pIcon;}
        protected set {pIcon = value;}
    }
    #endregion


    #region Constructor adn disposer
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize the contact.
    /// </summary>
    public Contact(string aName, Gdk.Pixbuf aIcon) : base()
    {
        pName = aName;
        pIcon = aIcon;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Release allocated resources.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Disposing(this, null);
    }
    #endregion


    #region Events
    /// <summary>
    /// Fired when the contact is being disposed.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler Disposing;
    #endregion  
}
```

Comment: Please add the part of the code where the exception is thrown to your question. Thanks.

Comment: Second Bobby's comment. It looks like you are trying to get a row back that doesn't exist, but without looking at the code it's difficult to tell what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 fields in your Contact class both defined as "Column = 0", so there is no column 1.

Try changing your pIcon field to this:

```
[Gtk.TreeNodeValue (Column = 1)]
private Gdk.Pixbuf pIcon;
```

That should instruct the TreeView that it should have 2 columns.

[This resource](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharpNodeViewTutorial) might be helpful to you.

Comment: I corrected it, but i still get the same exception.
And i compared my code to the one in your link, but I still can't find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. Making the accessed fields `public` instead of `private` solved my issue. Of course you should keep in mind that changing the visibility to `public` might not be the best solution, so you could wrap it in a read-only-property or something like that.